# Aggregate documents with diversity

Tags: mongodb

```
[
    {
        "_id": 0,
        "type": "cat"
    },
    {
        "_id": 1,
        "type": "dog"
    },
    {
        "_id": 2,
        "type": "cat"
    },
    {
        "_id": 3,
        "type": "unicorn"
    }
]
```

How to select `N` documents and preserve diversity based on the field `type`.

Examples:

- If I request 2 documents, I should never have two documents of type
  `"cat"`
- If I request 4 documents, I should only have 3 (only one of
  `"type": "cat"` should be included)

Comment: What is your mongod version?

Comment: @s.s it is v3.4.2

Comment: What if you always get the same documents?

Comment: not good. I guess you wanted to use `$sample`

Comment: Exactly, you need to use `$sample` to shuffle the documents from there you can group them and use $first or $last